# Chemical formula (or mathematical expression) in GNU R plot title

Tags: r, symbols, plotmath

How can i write H2o in the title of a plot?

H2 works:

```
plot(main=expression("H"[2]),0)
```

H2O fails:

```
plot(main=expression("H"[2]"O"),0)
```

This solution will work only, if i have a space in front " "

```
plot(main=expression(" "*H[2]*"O"),0)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You were close. This works:

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(H[2]*O))
```

The reason for this is that the `2` is a subscript to element `H` and you want to position element `O` next to the `H`. The notation `x * y` in an expression means juxtapose `x` with `y`, i.e. place `x` and `y` together. See `?plotmath` for more.