# Chemical formula + Text in Gnu R plot title

Tags: r, symbols

How can i write H2o in the title of a plot?

Thanks to this [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13147591/1749675) I can include a plain chemical formula in the headline with

```
plot(main=expression(H[2]*O),0)
```

The real formulas here are a bit more complicate and i want to abbreviate them and add these to the text, where needed.
But this fails:

```
h2o <- expression(H[2]*O)
plot(main=paste(h2o, "in the air"),0) # paste fails here :(
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that will let you have the chemical formula in a variable.

```
# note that .formula is either an expression or a character
# string that would define a valid expression
maketitle <- function(.formula, .other){
  .expression <- sprintf('%s ~ "%s"',as.character(.formula), .other)
  evalq(parse(text = .expression))
}


f <- expression(H[2]*O)
o <- 'blah blah'

plot(1:10, main = maketitle(f, o))
```

Remembering the perils of `eval(parse(text = ...))`,

> Personally I have never regretted trying not to underestimate my own
>   future stupidity.    -- Greg Snow (explaining why eval(parse(...)) is
>   often suboptimal, answering a question triggered by the infamous
>         fortune(106))
>         R-help (January 2007

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(H[2] * O ~ "in the air"))
```

Or

```
plot(1:10, main = expression(H[2] * O ~ "in" ~ the ~ air))
```

(The `in` needs to be quoted because it is part of the syntax of R that the parser captures first, as in `for(i in 1:10)`.)

The important point is the `x ~ y` notation places `x` and `y` next to one another with separation. **Do** read `?plotmath`!

The main point though is that whatever you supply here needs to be an expression as returned by `expression()`. Generally you don't need `paste()` *inside* an expression as you can include character strings in an expression for plotmath.

Comment: That works so far, but how can I read the chemical formula from a variable?

Comment: I don't think you can and I tried a few things including `bquote()`, `substitute()` etc.